# Follow the connections : recursive query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, connection

i have two columns of numbers.
the goal is starting from a number f.e. 55, to extract all 'connected' numbers
(starting with any of those numbers, should yield the same result)

```
 A  B
-----
56  55
55  56
69  55
35  55
47  55
60  55
22  55
26  47
 2  35
..... more data
```

in this case all numbers shown here : 55,56,35,69,60,22,47,2,26

I use the following query :

```
with recursive merge as (
   select A from T where A = 55 or B = 55
   union 
   select B 
    from T cm join merge m 
       on cm.A = m.A or cm.B = m.A
)
select * from merge
```

but I get back only those back : 55,56,35,69,60,22,47

I think using this will work :

```
with recursive merge as (
   select A from T where A = 55 or B = 55
   union 

  (
   select B 
    from T cm join merge m 
       on cm.A = m.A
    union
   select A 
    from T cm join merge m 
       on cm.B = m.A
  )
)
select * from merge
```

but Postgres does not allow to use "merge" more than ONCE in the recursive query !!?

My goal is starting with number to find all connected numbers across the "chain" i.e.

```
  55 => 56,35,69,60,22,47 => 2,26 ....
```

because :

```
  47 => 26
  35 => 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
with recursive
n (v) as (
  select case when t.a = 55 then t.b else t.a end
  from t
  where t.a = 55 or t.b = 55
 union
  select case when t.a = n.v then t.b else t.a end
  from n
  join t on t.a = n.v or t.b = n.v
)
select * from n
```

Result:

```
 v
--
56
69
35
47
60
22
55
 2
26
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hzVQjvqYnALHkpn7BA4jmZ/0).

Or... if you prefer to place the parameter in a single place:

```
with recursive
params as (select 55 as x), -- parameter only once
n (v) as (
  select case when t.a = p.x then t.b else t.a end
  from t
  cross join params p 
  where t.a = p.x or t.b = p.x
 union
  select case when t.a = n.v then t.b else t.a end
  from n
  join t on t.a = n.v or t.b = n.v
)
select * from n
```

Comment: can i use this query in update such that : update A = 1 where A in (select v from n)

Comment: Yes, you can use it for an`UPDATE`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-update.html

Comment: any idea to split this in pieces OR any advice to speed it up... using it on ~100_000 records and is very slow .. once I call it for every 100_000 X's, then it reduces to ~20_000 and again.... and I have to scale it to 1mln at least .. it will take a day to process :(

Comment: @sten If you want the query to "walk" 100k nodes, you'll need to add indexes. What indexes does the table have? I think you should ask a new question with the specific table and the indexes it has. Also, provide the current execution plan the query is using.

Comment: it has btree indexes on both cols... u right may be i will formulate it as another question

Answer (score 2):

This is following an undirected graph.  So, one solution is to create all the edges and then just follow them.

To avoid infinite cycles, keep a list of the visited nodes:

```
with recursive pairs as (
      select a, b
      from t
      union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select b, a
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select p.a, p.b, array[p.a, p.b] as els
      from pairs p
      where a = 55
      union all
      select p.a, p.b, els || p.b
      from cte join
           pairs p
           on cte.b = p.a
      where not (p.b = any (cte.els))
)
select b
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5ea067eb72a6c7a3a341eb7aa8904678) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

How about two CTEs `UNION`ed at the end?

```
WITH RECURSIVE
m1
AS
(
SELECT t.a
       FROM t
       WHERE a = 55
              OR b = 55
UNION
SELECT t.b 
       FROM t
            INNER JOIN m1
                       ON t.a = m1.a
),
m2
AS
(
SELECT t.a
       FROM t
       WHERE a = 55
              OR b = 55
UNION
SELECT t.a
       FROM t
            INNER JOIN m1
                       ON t.b = m1.a
)
SELECT m1.a
       FROM m1
UNION
SELECT m2.a
       FROM m2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ae7ddc30a089e60f6cef9652bd1a502f)